# Can't use code from manual (GoogleApiClient)

Tags: android, sdk, google-plus

I use code from [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started).

First problem - I copy and paste all this code, but then I start this activity I see toast with error message (and screen dimming).

Second problem - I can't use this code:

```
int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this);
    if (errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
    }
```

I see this error: [image]
This fragment from **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
...
```

}

P.S. I want use Google Plus for login in my app.

**UPDATE1** This screenshot from SDK Manager:[image]

Comment: In your SDK manager have you installed the latest Google Play services,Google support repository,Google Repository??

Comment: Did you do Step 2 of the page you're linking to?

Comment: No, I use Android Studio and I write in gradle compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'

Comment: Check out this link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/blob/master/QuickStart/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/accounts/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java. They are using GooglePlayServicesUtils

Comment: This method is correct, but in my code I change some classes (becouse google manuals dont correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param activity activity passed from activity that calls checkPlayServices().
 * @param context  getting the current context from the activity .
 */

    public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity, Context context) {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);


        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity,
                        Config.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                activity.finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
```